# Webpage Cross Browser CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with my form that looks okay in Firefox but it goes lower than I want it to on Chrome and IE. Also footers go higher in IE when there perfect in Chrome and FF.

I just want to know if there is any way I can make the CSS specific to each browser so if I opened my page in FF, IE or Chrome it would use the CSS specific to it.

Thanks

Update:

I have found this code to make a separate style sheet for IE:

```
<!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Is there one I can make for all the other browsers?

Comment: Generally speaking you don't need that for any other browsers except IE and not even for IE necessarily.. If you can't make code that works in all major browsers (minus IE) you might want to turn to css and html validators http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ - http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: you can use javascript to write out the stylesheet based on the type of browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE you can add a specific stylesheet using conditional comments:
http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

For Mozilla and Chrome you could use vendor specific tags.
In Chrome you would use something like this (As Chrome is webkit based, you add -webkit before tags):

```
#foo {
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
}
```

And in Mozilla you would use (add -moz before tags):

```
#foo {
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
}
```

You have to remember you cannot do this in all tags.

List for Mozilla: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions

List for Chrome:
http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/general/webkit_css_styles

Comment: @CharmingPrince yes your right this doesn't even work on my versions of chrome or FF. I think I'll try the JavaScript route. Thanks